# Access properties via subscripting in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have a custom class in Swift and I'd like to use subscripting to access its properties, is this possible?

What I want is something like this:

```
class User {
    var name: String
    var title: String

    subscript(key: String) -> String {
        // Something here
        return // Return the property that matches the key…
    }

    init(name: String, title: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
    }
}

myUser = User(name: "Bob", title: "Superboss")
myUser["name"] // "Bob"
```

**Update:** The reason why I'm looking for this is that I'm using [GRMustache](https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/view_model.md) to render from HTML templates. I'd like to be able to just pass my model object to the GRMustache renderer…

> GRMustache fetches values with the keyed subscripting objectForKeyedSubscript: method and the Key-Value Coding valueForKey: method. Any compliant object can provide values to templates.
>
> https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/view_model.md#viewmodel-objects

Comment: Properties are not stored as Dictionary so I guess you cannot access them like you want. What's wrong with `myUser.name`?

Comment: Since name and title are not private (because it is not possible yet) you would not have any benefit of it.

Comment: I updated the question with some reasoning on why I'd want something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(GRMustache author here)

Until a swift-oriented Mustache library is out, I suggest having your classes inherit from NSObject (so that they have the `valueForKey:` method). GRMustache will then fetch values with this method.

In case this would still not work (blank values in the rendering), you may try to disable GRMustache security features (see https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/blob/master/Guides/security.md#disabling-safe-key-access)

Should you experience any other trouble, please open an issue right into the repository: https://github.com/groue/GRMustache/issues

EDIT February 2, 2015: GRMustache.swift is out: http://github.com/groue/GRMustache.swift

Answer (score 21):

This is a bit of a hack using reflection. Something along the lines of the following could be used.

```
protocol PropertyReflectable { }

extension PropertyReflectable {
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in m.children {
            if child.label == key { return child.value }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

extension Person : PropertyReflectable {}
```

Then create a `Person` and access it's keyed properties.

```
let p = Person(name: "John Doe", age: 18)

p["name"] // gives "John Doe"
p["age"] // gives 18
```

You could modify the subscript to always return an interpolated string of the property value.

Comment: A nice solution but it should be noted that this (and reflection in general) does not work for computed properties in Swift

Answer (score 12):

Adding some syntax sugar to Benzi's answer:

```
protocol PropertyReflectable { }

extension PropertyReflectable {
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return m.children.first { $0.label == key }?.value
    }
}

struct Person: PropertyReflectable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Then create a `Person` and access it's keyed properties.

```
let p = Person(name: "John Doe", age: 18)

p["name"] // gives "John Doe"
p["age"] // gives 18
```

Comment: This is perfect. Allows me to access any property by string name

Comment: Why declare the protocol/struct, then extend it, as opposed to just writing the extension code in the initial declaration?

Comment: @AugustineCalvino because you cannot declare method bodies in a protocol, they can only go in extensions. Give it a shot yourself!

Comment: Ah I see the extension you were talking about now. It was a leftover from the original version. Cleaned it up.

Answer (score 10):

Using valueForKey should enable you to access properties using their names. Be sure that you're working with a object that inherit NSObject

```
class people: NSObject {
    var age: NSString = "44"
    var height: NSString = "153"
}

let person:people = people()

let stringVariable = "age"

person.valueForKey("age")
// Print "44"

person.valueForKey("\(stringVariable)")
// Print "44"
```

Comment: For Swift 3.0: `person.value(forKey: propertyName)`

Comment: How do you do a check if the value exists before getting it?

Answer (score 5):

Shim's answer above doesn't work anymore in Swift 4. There are two things you should be aware of.

First of all, if you want to use `value(forKey:)` function, your class must inherit `NSObject`.

Secondly, since Objective-C doesn't know anything about value type, you have to put the `@objc` keyword in front of your value type properties and Swift will do the heavy-lifting for you.

Here is the example:

```
import Foundation

class Person: NSObject {
    @objc var name: String = "John Dow"
    @objc var age: Int = 25
    @objc var height: Int = 180

    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        return self.value(forKey: key)
    }
}

let person: Person = Person()

person["name"] // "John Dow"
person["age"] // 25
person["height"] // 180
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do:

```
class User {
    let properties = Dictionary<String,String>()

    subscript(key: String) -> String? {
        return properties[key]
    }

    init(name: String, title: String) {
        properties["name"] = name
        properties["title"] = title
    }
}
```

Without knowing your use case I would **strongly** advise against doing this.

Another approach:

```
class User {
    var name : String
    var title : String

    subscript(key: String) -> String? {
        switch key {
            case "name" : return name
            case "title" : return title
            default : return nil
        }
    }

    init(name: String, title: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

It might be worth noting that Swift doesn't appear to currently support reflection by names. The `reflect` function returns a `Mirror` whose subscript is `Int` based, not `String` based.

Comment: I'm answering the question because I think it teaches about subscripting, switch and maybe a little bit about reflection (or the lack thereof). That said, I don't recommend doing any of the above.