# Class swift with parameter

Tags: arrays, swift, class, object

How do I get data from class `Object`?

```
class a{
    var data: String!
    var data2: String!
}
array = ["data","data2"]

var b = a()
b.data = "datatest"
b.data2 = "datatest2"
for i in 0 ..< array.count{
  print(b.\("array[i]"))
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28245227/2442804

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access properties via subscripting in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138705/access-properties-via-subscripting-in-swift)