# Using a string parameter to describe class property

Tags: swift, class, parameters

I want to write a function that takes a string and then prints the value of the class property with that name. In practice, there would be more than one property to choose form. For example...

```
class Apple{
  var juiciness : Int = 0
  init(juiciness: Int){
    self.juiciness = juiciness
  }
}

var myApple(juiciness : 10)

func printValue(property : String){
  print(Apple.property) // <-- I want to use the string to choose a property
}
```

Obviously, I can't do this code but I know there has to be a better solution than just I series of if statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24138705/access-properties-via-subscripting-in-swift

Comment: Do you *really* want to take a string? This would be much better implemented with a closure.

Comment: For future reference, this sort of functionality is called "reflection"

Comment: It doesn't need to be a string. How would I do it with a closure?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has done this for you. It is known as key-value observing(KVO).
Try the following code in the playground:

```
let label = UILabel()
print(label.value(forKey: "font"))
```

Your own class can support KVO by inheriting from NSObject:

```
class YourClass: NSObject{ ... }
```

Comment: Can I inherit from NSObject as an NSManagedObject?

Comment: @spogatetz NSManagedObject is a subclass of NSObject. You can simply inherit from NSManagedObject.